# Windows 7 Phone Navigate to URL (Type or Namespace "WebBrowserTask" could not be found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Win7.1 Phone App, via VS10

I take it that I need in include a namespace but cannot find resource online to tell me what that might be.  If it makes a difference this is going to be an ApplicationBarMenuItem.  Also wondering if I might need to know anything else to make sure I dont get any runtime or other issues.

```
void Google_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
    task.URL = "http://www.google.com";
    task.Show();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you have the needed references (Microsoft.Phone, Microsoft.Phone.Interop) and add:

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
```

There might be another "Tasks" reference that needs to be added.